# PHP - Passing/storing object instance methods by reference?

Tags: php, oop

As part of an attempt to get better at OOP, I'd like to implement a task queueing object that can build a list of tasks and execute them.  And I am writing in PHP, because most of the work that I do has to be in that language, and this is in the context of a very basic web framework I'm trying to build.

At its simplest, the tasks would consist of a function, an array of variables, a boolean to express that the task has been completed.

Is there a way to pass an object's function in a way that I can store it in a list and then execute it later?  Ideally I'd like something like:

```
$tasks->register($log->outputAllEntries, $logLevel);
$tasks->register($database->remove, $someRecord);
$tasks->register($log->toHTML, null);
```

and then later

```
$tasks->run();
```

And the run method in tasks would then run:

```
$log->outputAllEntries($logLevel);
$database->remove($someRecord);
$log->toHTML();
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to store the reference to the functions that I want to run... is there some way of doing that in PHP?  Or am I thinking about the problem ins a stupid kind of way?  This seems like something pretty easy to do in Javascript, but I'm not having any luck in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could implement this.  A simple approach would, instead of:

```
$tasks->register($log->outputAllEntries, $logLevel);
```

you would do

```
$tasks->register($log, 'outputAllEntries', array($logLevel));
```

You would have for your functions:

```
function register($class, $method, $params) {
    $this->tasks[] = array($class, $method, $params);
}

function run() {
    foreach($this->tasks as $task) {
        list($class, $method, $params) = $task;
        call_user_func_array(array($class, $method), array($params));
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is a good solution, and, as asked, is probably the "right solution"... I think that I was having a bit of a mental block, thinking that this would get me Log:: outputAllEntries()... but I'm seeing that when I try this, I get $class, where $class is the instance, not the Class... thanks.